# In MVC Razor, how can I correctly add querystring parameters to an html.actionlink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC Razor page where I am trying to add a querystring parameter to the URL.

```
<td>                
     @Html.ActionLink(item.Student_Name, "Index", "FourCourseAuditDetails", 
           new { filterByStudent = item.Student_Name})
</td>
```

My desired outcome is: `http://[server]/FourCourseAuditDetails/Index?filterByStudent="[item.Student_Name]"`, but when I test out the page, the anchor href attirubte looks like this: `http://[server]/[route of current view]?length=[integer value]`

According to the Intellsense and the Html.ActionLink descriptions, I am using the correct arguments, but clearly something is not right.

The thing that came to mind is that item.Student_Name is a string that contains spaces and commas. I tried `filterByStudent = item.Student_Name.toString()`, which didn't help. I still think that's the cause of the problem, but I don't know what else I can do. Any ideas?

Comment: Is FourCourseAuditDetails in the same controller as the current view?

Comment: I see one problem. I looked at the html code and see that the new is adding an attribute to the anchor tag, rather than forming the query string.

Comment: No it is not. It is in a different controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arise from the fact that there is no overload as `LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object)`

Use the overloaded method [LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)item.Student_Name, "Index", "FourCourseAuditDetails", 
       new { filterByStudent = item.Student_Name}, null)
```

Also need to type cast `item.Student_Name` to `string`.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge, You tested very quickly. Glad I could help